# List view web part search not working SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, search, list-view-web-part

For our On Premise SharePoint 2013 environment, the list view web parts do not seem to Search correctly. The default search box... We also have a SharePoint Online environment and of course it works perfectly on that environment

Does anyone know how I could look at debugging the issue, would it be a problem with the Search configuration. Search in general is working fine on the site.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide some more details? Do you see the search box at all? If you do, do you get an error message when searching (in console or ULS log), or does everything seemingly work fine just not returning any results? Happens for all lists, or just some?

Comment: I see the search box fine, I don't get any error message in the console, just the message 'Your search returned no results.' below the list view. Will get our Infrastructure admin to check the ULS logs and report back. Thanks

Comment: I would also check if any of the content in the list is searchable using the regular search box. If not, are you sure the list hasn't been set as not searchable by unchecking "Allow items from this document library to appear in search results" in the advanced list settings?